# how we can configure react-native-health-connect in RN Projects without using EXPO installation section

Tags: reactjs, react-native, healthkit

We are using the latest RN project where we want to add/implement react-native-health-connect to get steps etc. However, we are not able to achieve that with the documentation shared. If anyone have an idea please help us out with this.

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks!!

With EXPO it is working fine in our dummy environment. Same thing we are trying on our RN Project.